# Version-Compatbility for PouchDB-Replication with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have an Angular6-App with a PouchDB 7 where I plan a replication to a CouchDB-Server. The current option is a CouchDB-Server in version 1.6 only.

So the question is, if a replication form PouchDB in version 7 to this CouchDB in version 1.6 can work (for a two-way-replication so that different Angular-Clients can exchange changes over this CouchDB-Server).

I can't find any compatibillity list in the net to this topic...
Some hint's would be apprieciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB and PouchDB use the same replication protocol. There are some optimizations introduced in CouchDB 2.x, but PouchDB 7 will still be able to sync without a problem in CouchDB 1.6.

However, you *absolutely should not use CouchDB 1.6!!* 1.6 had some *very serious* [security flaws](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/whatsnew/1.7.html#version-1-7-0), which can essentially allow anyone to execute arbitrary code on your server. These were fixed in 1.7 and later. So please upgrade to at least 1.7.1 immediately!